# Can I relocate `.stack-work`?

Tags: haskell-stack

I want to develop under Windows, but have a guest Ubuntu system set up that ideally should perform the build and testing.

I still want to use all build tools and I think sharing `.stack-work` will probably a mess. So is there some terminal switch which makes `stack` use another directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, should have gone through `stack --help` first. There's `--work-dir`:

```
--work-dir WORK-DIR      Override work directory (default: .stack-work)
```